# How to transfer data from Quantopian to Excel

Tags: python, quantopian

Anyone know how you get a dataframe from Quantopian to excel - I try - results.to_excel
results are the name of my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Name of your DataFrame: `Result.to_csv("result.csv")`

here Result is your DataFrame Name , while to_csv() is a function